# Count same items in listview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview

I've been trying to count the same items in my listview but unfortunately I don't have any idea how to do it. Ok here is the question, I got a gridview that has datas for example in the first cell it would be **SUGAR** then when i click it, it will be displayed on the listview. I already done that. But what im trying to do is that when I click that **SUGAR** again in the gridview, the **SUGAR** on the listview would give me like a custom text **x2** so that I will know that its a second item with the same data.

Is it possible to do this? If so, How can I achieve this?

Comment: Loop through the listview and match the string that has been clicked, if a match is found, just updated that record in the listview.

Comment: @KazekageGaara can you give an example Sir? It would be more helpful tho I get what you are saying. I'm kinda new to android so it's kinda hard to understand :P TIA:)

Comment: I'll be able to provide a pseudo code, that will pretty much say whatever I have in the comment. So instead, I'll get back with a code snippet if possible later in the day. Sorry for the delay as I don't have access to a PC right now.